# C# Test if proxies are working before using them

Tags: c#, http, testing, proxy, socks

I want to check if the the proxies in my list are working before using them, is it possible?

It's easy for HTTP/HTTPS since you only have to use the webclient but for socks?

I tough this could work for all

```
public static bool SoketConnect(string addresse)
    {
        string[] proxy = addresse.Split(':');
        if (proxy.Count() == 2)
        {
            string host = proxy[0];
            int port = Convert.ToInt32(proxy[1]);

            var is_success = false;
            try
            {
                var connsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                connsock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, 200);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                var hip = IPAddress.Parse(host);
                var ipep = new IPEndPoint(hip, port);
                connsock.Connect(ipep);
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ping");
                        byte[] inStream = new byte[100];
                        connsock.Send(outStream);
                        connsock.ReceiveTimeout = 500;
                        connsock.Receive(inStream);
                        string message = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                        foreach (var bytes in inStream)
                        {
                            if (bytes != 0)
                            {
                                is_success = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        connsock.Disconnect(false);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        is_success = false;
                    }
                connsock.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                is_success = false;
            }
            return is_success;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

but i always get the exception

> "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly." System.Net.WebException

tldr; How to check if my socks proxies are working ( Which comes back to how to use a socks proxy)

EDIT: still doesn't help,need an answer
EDIT2 : Only pinging the proxy isn't the right thing to do

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you have to use them to see if they are working. I suggeset one of the following:

1. `ping` - With [Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) class in:

   ```
   using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

   private static bool CanPing(string address)
   {
       Ping myping = new Ping();

       try
       {
           PingReply reply = myping.Send(address, 2000);

           if (reply == null) 
               return false;

           return (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
       }
       catch (PingException e)
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Do a "Whats my IP?" through a proxy:

   ```
   public static void TestProxies() 
   {
       var lowp = new List<WebProxy> { new WebProxy("1.2.3.4", 8080), new WebProxy("5.6.7.8", 80) };

       Parallel.ForEach(lowp, wp => {

           var success = false;
           var errorMsg = "";
           var sw = new Stopwatch();

           try 
           {
                 sw.Start();
                 var response = new RestClient 
                 {
                   BaseUrl = "https://webapi.theproxisright.com/",
                   Proxy = wp
                 }.Execute(new RestRequest { Resource = "api/ip", Method = Method.GET, Timeout = 10000, RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json });

                 if (response.ErrorException != null) 
                    throw response.ErrorException;

                 success = (response.Content == wp.Address.Host);
           } 
           catch (Exception ex) 
           {
               errorMsg = ex.Message;
           } 
           finally 
           {
               sw.Stop();
           }
         });
   }
   ```

Comment: For the ping, pinging the proxy won't tell if it is not working,

2nd part, will it work with HTTP and SOCKS?